# one project to 2 android app in androud studio

Tags: android

i have build app using android studio , now inside my app there is 2 different user A,B . now i want to divide my app to 2 different app and as i know i cant just copy it

what i think to do is make another copy and change the package name as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) . but i want to ask is this is the best way to do it , or there are other things i need to be aware of

Note that i will upload these 2 app Separated in play store something like Grap and Grap Driver

Comment: Depends how much of the same codebase you use within your app. If the answer is A LOT then you should look into android  [build flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html). You will however need to provide another signing key to publish the app on the store but you can have both apps in the same android project

Comment: *i want to divide my app to 2 different app* - what does this mean? Be clear

Comment: @TimCastelijns , as i said i have 2 user A,B so i want app for A as user, and app for B as let say B Driver , so in the store user from A will download A , user from B will download B ,